# Python .values()[0] to pull out the first value of a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to pull out the first value of each key but it seems to be iterating through the values, one by one but not exactly how I intended, it is doing:

e.g

```
    def budget_options(self):
        models = self.shop.get_bicycle_models()
        for model, price in zip(self.shop.models.keys(), self.shop.models.values()[0]):
            print(model, price)
            if price * self.margin <= self.budget:
                print("The {} is available for a price of ${:.2f}.".format(model, price * self.margin))


evans_cycles = BicycleShop("Evans Cycles", { "BMC Road Machine": [125, 2], "Cannondale Synapse": [275, 5], "Pinnacle Laterite": [450, 1], "Fuji Transonic": [625, 3], "Cervelo R2": [750, 5], "Specialized Roubaix": [999, 1] })
```

Returning

```
('BMC Road Machine', 125)
The BMC Road Machine is available for a price of $150.00.
('Cannondale Synapse', 2)
The Cannondale Synapse is available for a price of $2.40.
```

When it should be

```
('BMC Road Machine', 125)
The BMC Road Machine is available for a price of $150.00.
('Cannondale Synapse', 275)
The Cannondale Synapse is available for a price of $330.00.
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I am following the Thinkful Python course trying to learn but I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: A dictionary has no order. The order of elements can change at very insert/removal/edit.

Comment: don't zip together keys and values, instead call `.items()`, you could be able to extract everything from there

Comment: Try instead - 
`for model, price in self.shop.items():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary has no order. This means that when you call `self.shop.models.keys()` and `self.shop.models.values()`, the values won't necessarily get returned in the same order as the keys, leading to the unexpected behaviour you described.

This is where the [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method comes in. What it does is simple:

> Return a copy of the dictionary’s list of (key, value) pairs.

You can use it in your code as follows:

```
def budget_options(self):
    models = self.shop.get_bicycle_models()

    for model, prices in self.shop.models.items(): # Change this
        price = prices[0] # Add this

        print(model, price)

        if price * self.margin <= self.budget:
            print("The {} is available for a price of ${:.2f}.".format(model, price * self.

evans_cycles = BicycleShop("Evans Cycles", { "BMC Road Machine": [125, 2], "Cannondale Synapse": [275, 5], "Pinnacle Laterite": [450, 1], "Fuji Transonic": [625, 3], "Cervelo R2": [750, 5], "Specialized Roubaix": [999, 1] })
```

When using huge dictionaries, you should use [`dict.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead. It works in exactly the same way but returns a generator instead of building the whole list of `(key, value)` pairs before returning it, reducing memory usage.

Comment: That's beautiful, thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of `zip(models.keys(), models.values())`, do `models.items()`, which returns a tuple of `(key, values)`.

```
for model, values in self.shop.models.items():
    price = values[0]  # this is the first item you wanted
    # do you stuff...
```

You might have a better description for `values`, but I don't know what the list `[125, 2]` represents, except from the fact that the first item is the price. But this is just nitpicking.